# how to remove a relationship between two node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I beginner at Neo4J.

I had build up some graph. Now I'm going to remove relationship between two now with cypher.

Anyone who tell me cypher query?

I have to remove relationship only.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Cypher ref card](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/) and the [online documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) for Cypher.

To delete a relationship, first `MATCH` on a pattern and bind the relationship to some variable, then use the `DELETE` clause to delete the relationship:

```
MATCH (:Person {name: "Bob"})-[r:LIKES]->(:Food {type: "Pizza"})
DELETE r
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `DELETE` clause to delete a relationship.